# Duda busqueda binaria recursiva vector no ordenado

Tags: c++, recursión

hay un ejercicio de recursividad resuelto que no entiendo:

> Impleméntese  el  método  int rsearch(int i,  int d,  const   T&  x)  de  la  clase   vector_t    que efectúa la  búsqueda     binaria    recursiva   en  un  vector  no  ordenado,   devolviendo la  posición    del elemento    encontrado  y   -1  si  no  lo  encuentra.

Este es el ejercicio resuelto:

```
template<class T>
int vector_t<T>:: rsearch(int i, int d, const T& x){

    int c=-1;

    if (i<=d){
        c=(i+d)/2;

        if (v_[c] !=x){
            int c1=rsearch(i,c-1,x);
            int c2=rsearch(c+1,d,x);
            c= max(c1,c2);
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

MI DUDA CON ESTE CÓDIGO: ¿por qué hace esto `c= max(c1,c2);`?

estas son las clases de las que hace uso:

```
template <class T>
class vector_t{
    private:
    T* v_;
    int sz_;
    public:
    vector_t(int sz);
    ~vector_t(void);
    int get_sz(void) const;
    T get_v(int pos) const;
    T& get_set_v(int pos);
};
```

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la posición del elemento encontrado es un numero positivo o cero `num_positivo` y si no lo encuentra es `-1` el `max(-1,num_positivo)=num_positivo`, max se el maximo entre dos numeros

`rsearch` funciona calculando el centro del vector si el valor buscado es el centro devuelve la posicion de este, si no lo busca recursivamente con rsearch a la izquierda y rsearch a la derecha como los indices de un arreglo son positivos el maximo siempre va a ser el valor encontrado si se da

```
template<class T>
int vector_t<T>:: rsearch(int i, int d, const T& x){
     //i es izquierda d derecha y x el valor a buscar c de centro 
    int c=-1;//valor por defecto

    if (i<=d){  // si divides el vector puede que no halla una mitad

        c=(i+d)/2;//Toma el elemento del centro de la lista

        if (v_[c] !=x){ //Si No es el elemento del centro
            int c1=rsearch(i,c-1,x); //Buscar en la lista a la izquierda
            int c2=rsearch(c+1,d,x); //Buscar en la lista a la derecha
            c= max(c1,c2);// si es mayor que -1 es que encontro el Elemento
        }
    }

    return c;//Si c no fue encontrado devuelve -1 q era el valor original
}
```

esta funcion obliga a ejecutar la busqueda a la derecha aun si se ha encontrado a la izquierda, mejor quedaria asi:

```
template<class T>
int vector_t<T>:: rsearch(int i, int d, const T& x){

    int c=-1;//valor por defecto

    if (i<=d){  // si divides el vector puede que no halla una mitad

        c=(i+d)/2;//Toma el elemento del centro de la lista

        if (v_[c] !=x){ 
            c=rsearch(i,c-1,x);
            if(c==-1)c=rsearch(c+1,d,x); //Si no lo encontro al la izquierda buscar a la derecha
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

Y yo personalmente prefiero este estilo de código:

```
template<class T>
int vector_t<T>:: rsearch(int i, int d, const T& x){
    if (i>d)return -1; //El indice de la izquierda no puede ser mayor que el de la derecha
    int c=(i+d)/2;//El centro de la lista si i==d es 2i/2 ==i==d
    if (v_[c] ==x)return c;
    c=rsearch(i,c-1,x);
    if(c!=-1)return c;
    c=rsearch(c+1,d,x);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación

Answer (score 1):

Es una forma abreviada de decir:

```
if ((c1 == -1) && (c2 == -1)) {
   c = -1; // No encontrado en ningún subárbol.
} else {
  if (c1 == -1) { // c2 != -1
     c = c2;  // Encontrado en el subárbol 2.
  } else {  // c1 != -1
     c = c1;  // Encontrado en el subárbol 1.
  }
}
```